# dir, clear, amongst other commands close terminal and ssh connection

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, terminal

I'm connected to my server using ssh. I was trying some things and copy pasted exactly `http://127.0.0.1/folder/script.php` to the terminal. After pressing enter, it closed the ssh. After logging in again it just keeps on closing if I use dir, clear or some other commands. I can use cd, but the connection simply closes with no errors with a lot of commands. Any idea on why? Didn't found anything about it....

EDIT: it seems to only close if the commands are issued in the root folder... help?

EDIT: WTH, THE PROBLEM IS IN MY LOCAL PC AFTER ALL, **EVERYTHING** IS ROOTED, EVERY SINGLE FILE / FOLDER HAS A LOCK, WHAT IS GOING ON?

Comment: You need to get someone to look directly at your PC. This is unlikely to get resolved over the Innernet.

Comment: Try executing the `false` or the `true` commands; what happens? On which of these commands does the connection close? Is the behavior deterministic? If it's deterministic and only closes on `false`, does executing a `set +e` repair the behavior for the rest of the session?

Comment: apparently you are executing some php code in script.php... what is its content?